# Cannot Understand the Dimension Parameter in the Color Panel Constructor?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ColorPanel(Color col){
        this.setBackground(col);
    }
    public ColorPanel(Color col , int width,int height){

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        this.setBackground(col);
    }

}
```

My question is in this line :"`setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height))`"
why do I have to write `new Dimension` and why I can't just put in something like
"`setPreferredSize(width,height)`" pls help and tell me why do i need to say `new Dimension`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling Jpanel's setPreferredSize function (via the superclass) which only accepts Dimension as the input http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)

HTH,

Comment: OK thank you but stii why add the new isnt new only used to declare objects of an imported class

Comment: @RayyanMerchant - not only imported classes but objects of all classes are constructed using new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

JPanel has indeed a single [`setPreferredSize(Dimension d)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)).
The reason behind that is that it behaves differently when user has explicitly used setPreferredSize(d).
You can check that [`JPanel.isPreferredSizeSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isPreferredSizeSet()) returns `null` if you didn't set it.
Setting the preferred size to `null` restores the default behavior.
This behavior affects Swing layout and GUI when drawing the JPanel and its content.